# Is there a way to extract NCT ID, approval order, post-approval study links from PMA database with openFDA api?

Tags: api, openfda, database

I am wondering if it is possible to add more searchable fields to the openFDA api PMA database such as NCT ID, approval order link and post-approval study link? Or adding something to determine which results have the approval order or post-approval study documents as the statement_or_summary in 510(K) database? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no plan to expand fields in the PMA dataset at this point, but if that changes, we'll definitely let you know.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead